# Java Incompatible types

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
public class redtry4 {
    public static void main(String[]args)throws IOException{
        BufferedReader IN = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String[]numx = new String[10];
        System.out.println("Enter 10 different numbers:");
        for(int b=0; b<10; b++)
        {
            System.out.println("Accepted numbers are:"+"\n"+b);
            numx[b]=Integer.parseInt(IN.readLine());

        }
    }
}
```

> I keep getting error: Incomptaible type on numx[b]=Integer.parseInt(IN.readLine());.

Comment: You also consider using `Scanner` to read input from the console ;)

Answer (score 2):

`numx` is a String and the return type of `Integer.parseInt(IN.readLine())` is an int, hence the error.

Either change your num array to be a string array

```
int[]numx = new int[10];
```

or don't use `Integer.parseInt` to covert the value to integer.

```
numx[b]=IN.readLine();
```

choice is yours, depending on your need.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
String[]numx = new String[10];
```

to

```
int[]numx = new int[10];
```

If you want to parse the inputs as integers, store them in an int array.
If you still want to store them in a String array, don't call `parseInt`.